# Views within non-Backbone templates and rerendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have an app that has a single page main.html, and a few major templates admin.html, user.html, etc. This app is not currently backbone, just some sections of it (slow migration).

In the admin page, I have BB views for users, etc. When a user selects a path to /admin/users, e.g. then a master template loader (non-BB) loads admin.html into a standard location in main.html, and then runs reset on the usersView:

```
// pseudocode
function() {
  master.loadTemplate("admin.html").then(function(){usersView.reset();});
}
```

admin.html contains several elements, only one of which is the template for usersView. So it might look like:

```
<div id="admin-fragment">
  <div id="admin-users">
    <!-- template for usersView -->
  </div>
  <div id="admin-something else">
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I load the script that contains usersView, it looks like:

```
UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#admin-users"
});
```

All pretty good. Here is the issue.

Sometimes, a user might go somewhere else in this single page app, then go back to /admin/users. So the master template loader loads (and sometimes reloads, depending) the entire admin.html. But the usersView is *already* attached to the existing (now orphaned) #admin-users.

How do I resolve this? I see two ways, could use some ideas:

- instead of usersView.reset() when I select /admin/users, create a new usersView:

  // pseudocode
  function() {
    master.loadTemplate("admin.html").then(function(){usersView = new UsersView();});
  }

My concern is the performance and management hit.

- somehow tell the existing usersView to "reparent" / "reconnect", i.e. find the element anew.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Update on this: I tried doing option A, but then I have the classic zombie view problem. And because these views are composites - I have one for the edit form, one for the search box, one for the search results, and a wrapper to it all - doing Bailey's view.close() won't help unless I go all the way down with each one. What a mess!

Answer (score 0):

See these posts on good patterns for rendering nested views in Backbone:

- [Assigning Backbone Subviews Made Even Cleaner](http://ianstormtaylor.com/assigning-backbone-subviews-made-even-cleaner/)
- [Rendering Views in Backbone.js Isn't Always Simple](http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/)